Google Sheets QUERY query to SELECT cell from column 2 row 2
I am trying to create a stock portfolio dashboard using google sheets. For part of the dashboard I want to produce the  % return over the previous 7 days (and 30, and 90 but figuring this out once should make other intervals a breeze).
Using the basic googlefinance function to get historical market close stock prices produces a two column table with the date and market close price going back however far you want.
What I'm trying to do is write a function that returns just the one market close value for the earliest day specified in the function which will always be in B2 if function is entered in A1. This value could then be used to calculate % gain/loss compared to the current stock price.
Here is the formula to produce market close prices for SPY going back 7 days:
=googlefinance("SPY", "price", today()-7, today())
7 day market close price
In this example, I would want cell A1 with the formula to return 511.29, the value in cell B2.
The closest I've gotten is returning only the price column using this query:
=query(googlefinance("SPY", "price", today()-7, today()), "select Col2 label Col2 ''")
Query returning price row
So the "select Col2 label Col2 ''" first only selects the second column and then removes the header row with label Col2. This results in the value I want in cell A1, but I get additional unwanted values below.
What's the best way to refine this to return only the oldest price in cell A1? Thanks!


You may try:
=index(googlefinance("SPY", "price", today()-7, today()),2,2)

